# Multiple Click events on one Button?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

So basically what I've done below is create a simple 'Animated Button' subclass of the Button that I intend to use in my UI that does basic animations. I made it a subclass intentionally because I am new with Xamarin, and since Forms is my first project, I wanted to avoid a custom renderer because I'm not familiar with all three different platform's individual code.

```
    class AnimatedButton : Button
{
    public AnimatedButton(string buttonText, ImageSource backgroundImage = null)
    {
        Text = buttonText;
        //TextColor = Color.FloralWhite;

        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
        Opacity = 0.8;
        BorderRadius = 25;
        BorderWidth = 1;
        BorderColor = Color.AliceBlue;

        Clicked += AnimatedButton_Clicked;

        if (backgroundImage != null)
        {
            //Set Background Image
        }

    }

    private async void AnimatedButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.ScaleTo(0.9, 50, Easing.SinIn);
        await this.FadeTo(1, 50, Easing.SinOut);
        await this.FadeTo(0.8, 50, Easing.SinIn);
        await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.SinOut);
    }
}
```

See? Simple. Anyways in my user interface I need my buttons to cause other events like menu movements and all that. So obviously this code below doesn't work but i'm showing what I was hoping i could do:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowCollection[i]);
            AnimatedButton button = new AnimatedButton(menuOptions.MyTypeDataList[1].TitleText);
            button.Clicked += TestClicked;
            grid.Children.Add(button, 0, i + 1);
        }
    }

    private void TestClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Perform Action
    }
```

Only the last Clicked += TestClicked event works. Is the animation not working because I can't have multiple click handlers attached to the same button? Or am i just doing this wrong?  How should I go about this in Xamarin

Thanks

Comment: if you're familiar with winforms, you might know we often **override** `OnClick` method instead of registering Click event in custom controls.

Comment: Try to put the code in the multiple events in separate methods after that when you execute the wanted click, execute all the wanted methods. So in event1-> Event1(); in event2->Event2(); in event3->Event3(); in your new button click Event1();Event2()Event3(); Did you try this and if yes what is the problem ?

Comment: Lei yang, I didn't know about that and would be interested to try it out! Appreciate if you have any examples.

Comment: Mybirthname, I thought about that but because the events would be different depending on where the button was in the UI and there were many different buttons from this new subclass that, if I'm understanding you correctly, I can't just put all my events inside of my first button click because the events will always be different

Comment: I see what you are trying to accomplish and it should work. Does async have anything to do with it not working? You can bind multiple event handlers to a single event and they will all be invoked. It is actually often the cause of memory leaks because the mutliple handlers aren't disposed when the object is.

Comment: @MikeH in your class type override then you should see those virtual methods

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins You may be right about the Async vs sync methods interfering, I will try that as soon as i get the chance. That is interesting about the memory leaks, and thanks for informing me that I should be able to handle multiple events on one click. How should i go about removing the handlers to prevent these types of memory leaks issues? Should i do button -= EVENT to handle it?

Comment: I had a massive silver light project with the issue, which is very similar to wpf. The handlers were added on load and not in the constructor (not sure why) and every time the control went out of view it would unload and when it was brought back into view it would call load and wire up an additional event handler. The if referenced by external classes still int scope controls would never dispose (no IDisposable) but they would remain in scope. And yes, -= removes the handler.

Comment: Have you looked at this yet?

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins Hey man yeah i just had a chance to look at it now. I'm not sure why it wasn't working before but now multiple event handlers on one button is working when before it wasn't! Both with and without Async. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: @LeiYang I checked for the OnClick method but in xamarin forms the button doesn't seem to have any OnClick to override. Just has some other basic things like ToString and Equals. Interesting thought thought i appreciate the feedback

Comment: This behaviour is common in Android. I have this problem too. It is not just Click, but all events.